# additional criteria SQL query [Access 2013]

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to remove some entries from my SQL query based on a different table but I always get multiple results for the original query as soon as I try to add the third table.

My query looks like this

[image]

My listbox shows different entries based on "ID_Projekte" (table in the middle). Each "ID_Projekte" is linked to several entries in "tbl_Projekte_Phasen" (right side).Now I would like to remove some entries based on "ID_Projektphasen_FK".

Example:
If an entry from the "main table" has an entry on the right side where "ID_Projektphasen_FK" is "4" or "10" I don't want to show it in the listbox

My problem is as soon as I add "ID_Projektphasen_FK" to the query I get multiple entries because it lists the project for each entry on the right side.

The SQL code looks like this right now:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    tbl_Projekte.ID_Projekte, 
    tbl_Projekte.Projektname,
    tbl_Werkzeugtypen.Bezeichnung, 
    tbl_Projekte.Werkzeugnummer,
    tbl_Projekte.Projekttyp,
    tbl_Projekte.Bemerkung
FROM 
    tbl_Werkzeugtypen INNER JOIN (tbl_Projekte INNER JOIN tbl_Projekte_Phasen 
                                  ON tbl_Projekte.ID_Projekte = tbl_Projekte_Phasen.ID_Projekte_FK) 
    ON tbl_Werkzeugtypen.ID_Werkzeugtypen = tbl_Projekte.Werkzeugtyp
WHERE 
(((tbl_Projekte.Projekttyp)=[Formulare]![frm_Kundenauftraege]![Projekttyp]))
ORDER BY tbl_Projekte.Projektname DESC;
```

Hope I described my problem clearly and someone is able to help me

Answer (score 0):

If `ID_Projektphasen_FK` is only needed as criteria, don't show it in the result (untick "Anzeigen"). Then it won't create additional records in the result.

Alternatively, don't use `DISTINCT` but `GROUP BY` all columns, and set the *Funktion* of `ID_Projektphasen_FK` to *Bedingung* (condition).

Comment: failed again due to this stupid little tick -.- thank you.

Unfortunately it is not working 100%. Example:

Project "A" has a single corresponding table entry with "ID_Projektphasen_FK" = 4 --> your solution will hide the entry from the listbox

Project "B" has 2 corresponding table entries with "ID_Projektphasen_FK" = 1 and one with  "ID_Projektphasen_FK"  = 4 it will not hide the project completely. I need to hide the project in this case as well

So if there is any corresponding entry with "ID_Projektphasen_FK" = 4 dont show the whole project

Comment: To solve this, please add sample data to your question. I suggest to remove `tbl_Werkzeugtypen` from the question, it's irrelevant for the problem. @Moritz